# Add retention policy to API Gateway logs published to CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I have to add retention policy to API Gateway Cloudwatch logs, hence I cannot use the aws provided policy to do so i.e. `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs`

So instead I created my own role with custom policy :

```
ApiGatewayCloudWatchLogsRole:
Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
DependsOn: APIGFunctionLogGroup
Properties:
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: 2012-10-17
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service:
            - apigateway.amazonaws.com
        Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
  Path: / 
  Policies:
    - PolicyName: APIGatewayPushLogsPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
              - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
              - 'logs:DescribeLogGroups'
              - 'logs:DescribeLogStreams'
              - 'logs:GetLogEvents'
              - 'logs:FilterLogEvents'
            Resource: '*'
```

And then created LogGroup with retention as :

```
APIGFunctionLogGroup:
Type: 'AWS::Logs::LogGroup'
Properties:
  RetentionInDays: 30
  LogGroupName: !Join 
    - ''
    - - API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_
      - !Ref MyRestApi
```

And passed the above created role to `AWS::ApiGateway::Account`

```
ApiGatewayAccount:
Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Account'
DependsOn: APIGFunctionLogGroup
Properties:
  CloudWatchRoleArn: !GetAtt 
    - ApiGatewayCloudWatchLogsRole
    - Arn
```

But while deploying my API Gateway I am getting error as :

[image: ERROR]

I have the trust policy as well but API Gateway Account is not getting created.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the log group yourself, before APIgateway does you should be able to use the existing policy/service role.

Comment: what is the problem with the way I am trying to do ? I cannot understand a reason for it not to work

Comment: It's possible that CloudFormation is checking the permissions that role has and is not allowing it. Confirm by manually creating the role and configuring apigateway to use it via the console.

Comment: This answer is correct, just make sure to add the LogGroup resource in the DependsOn section of the API GW or Deployment resources.